# how can I calculate how many characters trimstart removes

Tags: string, tabs, trim

I have a string, and I need to calculate the number of spaces that I remove when I do trimStart.
For example, I have the following string `\t\t  \tabcs`
so I have two tabs and two spaces and another tab that will be removed using trim start (the rest is non space related chars).
I need to know how many spaces will be removed. since I don't know how much is \t, I can't just count it as a single char.
(My purpose is to calculate the column shift of a string due to the trimming action. Obviously comparing the lengths before and after the trim will not return me the desired result.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: ISTM you need to expand the tabs (i.e. convert them into the appropriate number of spaces) first. You can either just calculate the final column number (each space increases the column number by one, each tab moves the column number to the next multiple of 8 -- or whatever your tab size is), or you could generate a new string with the tabs expanded.  If you generate a new string then you can count the number of leading spaces directly, or compare the length of that string before trimming with the length of the string after trimming.

Comment: The problem is that tab can be different since I accept the string from different sources and systems.

Comment: Then there is no solution unless you can either discover what the tab character means for those different sources (have them tell you, or set up some mechanism that recognises the source of the string and knows what tab means for each source), or have those other sources expand the tab before they send you the string.